# Error in Java rescale method

Tags: java

**Homework problem. Hi, I am new to Java. I am trying to write a `rescale` method, but it is showing an error.**

Question: Define a method called `rescale` that takes a double named `magnitude` as its parameter. When you call this method on a vector, it should return a new vector whose direction is the same, but whose magnitude is the one supplied as the parameter.

```
public class Vector {

    private double deltaX, deltaY;

    public Vector(double deltaX, double deltaY) {
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
        this.deltaY = deltaY;
    }

    public double getDeltaX() {
        return deltaX;
    }

    public double getDeltaY() {
        return deltaY;
    }

    public double magnitude() {
        return Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    }

    public Vector deflectX() {
        Vector c = new Vector(-deltaX, deltaY);
        return c;
    }

    public Vector deflectY() {
        Vector c = new Vector(deltaX, -deltaY);
        return c;
    }

    public Vector plus(Vector x) {
        Vector c = new Vector(this.deltaX + this.deltaX, this.deltaY + this.deltaY);
        return c;
    }

    public Vector minus(Vector y) {
        Vector d = new Vector(this.deltaX - y.deltaX, this.deltaY - y.deltaY);
        return d;
    }

    public Vector scale(double factor) {
        Vector s = new Vector(factor * deltaX, factor * deltaY);
        return s;
    }

    public Vector rescale(double magnitude) {
        if (magnitude == 0) {
            Vector s = new Vector(deltaX, 0);
        } else {
            Vector s = new Vector(deltaX, deltaY);
        }

        double d = s.magnitude();
        if (magnitude == 0) {
            Vector s = new Vector(deltaX, deltaY);
        }

        return s.scale(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting while trying to do so?

Comment: the code is not working, this is the error. Thanks for asking.

Comment: I formatted your code to make it easier to see where the error is.  You haven't told us where the error is but I'm guessing it's because of how you define `Vector s`...

Comment: Here's a hint...do you think `double d = s.magnitude();` can "see" `Vector s`???